# JavaScript ternary if x && y else

Tags: javascript

```
$scope.input.opening_hours = place.opening_hours && place.opening_hours.weekday_text ? place.opening_hours.weekday_text : '';
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weekday_text' of
>   undefined(…)

```
if ( place.opening_hours && place.opening_hours.weekday_text ) {
    $scope.input.opening_hours = place.opening_hours.weekday_text;
} else {
    $scope.input.opening_hours = '';
}
```

I am trying to make a ternary version of this if statement but I get the error  above. Whats the best way to simplify this to a simpler statement.

Comment: opening_hours is undefined

Comment: I think precedence of operators is different to what you expect, and you're actually running:
$scope.input.opening_hours = place.opening_hours && (place.opening_hours.weekday_text ? place.opening_hours.weekday_text : '';)

Comment: Use parenthesis . However I can't understand why you need to make that task, is better readable the original `if()`

Comment: Add some parenthesis around the bool expression

Comment: @RubenSerrate Nah, I think this would run correctly. He should definitely use parenthesis but this should be valid

Comment: Evidence that in this case, parenthesis doesn't matter: `false && true ? "Is True" : "Is False";` returns `"Is False"`, while `false && (true ? "Is True" : "Is False");` returns `false`

Comment: @Mahi Seems to be the only one correct so far. Javascript can't find `place.opening_hours` because it's undefined

Comment: In order to be safe, you'll probably need a `typeof place.opening_hours != 'undefined'` which means nesting some ifs.  I personally do like ternary operators for simple things but not for nested ifs so I would recommend expanding this.

Comment: Thanks everyone. My mind went blank but I needed parenthesis around the boolean expression. @MarcosPérezGude if you add it as an answer I can approve it

Comment: @Howzieky true && false ? false : true --> you get true

Therefore that is executing as true && (false ? false : true)

Comment: @RubenSerrate This happens because you have the order at the end switched up. `true && false` becomes `false`. Ternary works like `boolean ? ifTrue : ifFalse;`. In your example, you've flipped the `return1 : return2;`, so you're basically returning the opposite of `boolean`

Comment: @Bangsi I answer it :) Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I tell you in comments, you need to add parenthesis:

```
$scope.input.opening_hours = (place.opening_hours && place.opening_hours.weekday_text) ? place.opening_hours.weekday_text : '';
```

And you can improve:

```
$scope.input.opening_hours = ((place.opening_hours && place.opening_hours.weekday_text) ? place.opening_hours.weekday_text : '');
```

The latter ensures that inner parenthesis will be executed before all. It's like maths, the inner parenthesis needs to be executed before outer parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the ternary operator, this'll do just fine:

```
... = place.opening_hours && place.opening_hours.weekday_text || '';
```

Perhaps even:

```
... = (place.opening_hours || {}).weekday_text || '';
```

Having said that, the ternary expression *should* have worked, I don't know why it supposedly doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

With AngularJS:

```
if (angular.isObject(place) && place.hasOwnProperty('opening_hours')) {
    var openingHours = place.opening_hours;
    if (angular.isObject(openingHours) && openingHours.hasOwnProperty('weekday_text')) {
        $scope.input.opening_hours = openingHours.weekday_text;
    }
    else {
         $scope.input.opening_hours = '';
    }
}
else {
    $scope.input.opening_hours = '';
}
```

With pure JS:

```
// check if a object value
function isObject (_object) {
    return Object.keys(_object).length >= 0 && _object.constructor === Object
}

if (isObject(place) && place.hasOwnProperty('opening_hours')) {
    var openingHours = place.opening_hours;
    if (isObject(openingHours) && openingHours.hasOwnProperty('weekday_text')) {
        $scope.input.opening_hours = openingHours.weekday_text;
    }
    else {
         $scope.input.opening_hours = '';
    }
}
else {
    $scope.input.opening_hours = '';
}
```

Using [pathExists JS](https://gist.github.com/olaferlandsen/d37590fd251553b73ba56fc114dfcf0d)(basic):

```
if (objectPathExists(place, 'opening_hours.weekday_text')) {
    $scope.input.opening_hours = openingHours.weekday_text;
} else {
    $scope.input.opening_hours = '';
}
```

Ternary:

```
$scope.input.opening_hours = objectPathExists(place, 'opening_hours.weekday_text') ? openingHours.weekday_text : ''
```

Using [pathExists JS](https://gist.github.com/olaferlandsen/d37590fd251553b73ba56fc114dfcf0d) (prototype):

```
if (place.pathExists('opening_hours.weekday_text')) {
    $scope.input.opening_hours = openingHours.weekday_text;
} else {
    $scope.input.opening_hours = '';
}
```

Ternary:

```
$scope.input.opening_hours = place.pathExists('opening_hours.weekday_text') ? openingHours.weekday_text : ''
```